# Haskell Pattern Matching Booleans

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I need help to fix this Haskell function using pattern matching. It should only return true if every formula in the list of formulas is True. Here is what I have so far:

```
eval_list :: [Formula] -> Bool
eval_list (f:fx) = (eval_list f) && (eval_list fx)
```

here is how Formula is defined:

```
data Formula = And Formula Formula
             | Not Formula
             | Con Bool
             deriving Show
```

Comment: How do you evalaute the `Formula`? You are calling `eval_list` on it, but that is done for lists, not for the formulas of that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to implement the case for an empty list. Since you each time recurse with a list item that is one item shorter than the previous call, eventually you will make a recursive call with an empty list.

Another problem is that you call `eval_list f`, but `f` is the first item of your list and thus a `Formula` object, not a list of `Formula`s. You likely should use a `eval_formula` to evaluate the formula.

You thus can implement this with:

```
eval_list :: [Formula] -> Bool
eval_list [] = True
eval_list (f:fx) = eval_formula f && eval_list fx
```

where you will have to implement `eval_formula` yourself.

You do not need to use explicit recursion. You can for example work with [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all):

```
eval_list :: Foldable f => f Formula -> Bool
eval_list = all eval_formula
```

In order to evaluate a single `Formula`, you can use recursion, the function thus will look like:

```
eval_formula :: Formula -> Bool
eval_formula (And f1 f2) = …
eval_formula (Not f) = …
eval_formula (Con b) = …
```

where I leave implement the `…` parts as an exercise.